# What type of thread method should I use for continuous work?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

My application is currently using ordinary threads to produce servers, clients and even a thread which swaps WiFi networks and starts the previous. Those threads run in the background and dont have any impact on the UI so it is something I was looking for, but the problem is that when I reenter the application all those threads are recreated. Is it possible to create a singleton thread which will be possible to control when we reopen the application?

Android offers some classes also:

**Service**: but it uses the UI thread...

**AsyncTask**: probably a better candidate

**IntentService**: has a worker thread which could be manipulated? Probably best option from above.

Any thoughts/opinions will be highly appreciated. :)

EDIT:

Also why I would want to change my ordinary threads into some other method is because Android will prioritize ordinary threads to get killed.

Thread call hierarchy:

**MainActivity** -> **NetworkSwap**(infinite process which is scanning, connecting and swaping WiFi networks), **ServerTCP**(infinitely listening for connections) , **ServerUDP**(infininetely listening for connections)

**Networkswap** -> **ClientUDP** (sends broadcast request to serverUDP and ends)

**ServerUDP** -> **ClientTCP** (sends request to serverTCP and ends)

Comment: You can create threads in a service, just like you can create them from an activity. If you use a service, your worker threads will continue to work even if your activity is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not entirely clear to me what you're using these threads for. From the title it seems you're doing ongoing work, but in the description it sounds like sometimes you do smaller discrete chunks of work. It's also not clear whether these types of work are related.

That said, with ongoing work I'd say to move your currently existing thread to be managed by a regular Service, thus giving a lifetime that is independent of activities and can do ongoing background work. For smaller discrete chunks of work, IntentService is a better match. If you have these two types of work and they're not very related, you could even consider having both types of services (it sounds like you have multiple threads as is anyway).